# Using flask, templates . Error template not found

Tags: python, flask

**flaskblog.py** contains the code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return '<h1> About page!</h1>'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug= True)
```

**home.html** contains the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Home Page! </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run flaskblog.py, I get

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When I put **http://127.0.0.1:5000/**  in safari, I get a page starts with

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound
```

Comment: What's your folders structure? is the home.html file inside the `templates` folder?

Comment: Yes it is inside. @luigibertaco

Answer (score 1):

I've just executed your code locally with success, please doublecheck your file structure, it must be:

```
/flaskblog.py
/templates
    /home.html
```

Comment: Hi @MustafaAlbairmani glad to help. if the answer helped, you can mark it as the correct solution to help other users that have the same problem.